Azure Functions Typescript Compiles but Can't Find Module at Runtime
I have written a declaration library in TS that I've turned into a Node module. It consists entirely of .d.ts files, including an index.d.ts like this:
export * from "./file1";
export * from "./file2";
export * from "./file3";

it has this package.json:
{
  "description": "Types for foo repository",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "name": "@company/foo",
  "main": "",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/company/repo.git"
  },
  "version": "1.0.4"
}

This setup looks exactly like another package we're depending on; luxon.
tsc works fine, and even VSCode is linking the files correctly in imports (no errors). However, at runtime I get "cannot find module" errors:
[2024-06-21T17:39:35.273Z] Worker was unable to load function Function: 'Cannot find module '@company/foo'
[2024-06-21T17:39:35.273Z] Worker failed to load function: 'Function' with functionId: 'fejaklvc-afae-4aee-adc4-a635657141dc'.
[2024-06-21T17:39:35.276Z] Require stack:
[2024-06-21T17:39:35.277Z] Result: Failure
[2024-06-21T17:39:35.277Z] - /home/person/dev/repo/api/dist/Function/types.js

When I go to /home/person/dev/repo/api/dist/Function/types.js in VSCode it doesn't show any errors in the require. Tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "composite": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/typings"],
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./common/@types/*"]
    }
  }
}

I have tried different targets. Totally lost. Why won't it find the module at runtime?

I've tried different targets in the tsconfig. No change.


@DasariKamali I'm a little confused; there is no code. There is a few declaration files. The main; index.d.ts; is simply a list of exports from other files as stated in the question.
